# Why does delay() suspend a coroutine but yield() doesn't, inside Kotlin's runTest{} function?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, testing, coroutine, yield

The simplified test below has been converted from using `runBlocking` to `runTest` to make it work with Kotlin Multiplatform. However, `runTest` causes it to fail. Debugging shows that the delay in job1 suspends the coroutine and job2 becomes active. I would then expect the `yield()` call to suspend job2 and for job1 to become active again, allowing it to finish before job2. However, for some reason it doesn't. The while loop continues until the timer runs out and the test fails.

```kotlin
class YieldTest {
    @Volatile
    var locked: Boolean = false

    @Test
    fun test_delay_yields_coroutine() = runTest {
        val clock = Clock.System
        val timeSource = TimeSource.Monotonic

        val job1 = async {
            locked = true
            delay((500).toLong())
            locked = false

            timeSource.markNow()
        }

        val job2 = async {
            val timeout = clock.now().plus(5, DateTimeUnit.SECOND)
            while (locked && clock.now() <= timeout) {
                yield()
            }

            timeSource.markNow()
        }

        val job1Finish = job1.await()
        val job2Finish = job2.await()

        assertTrue(job1Finish < job2Finish)
    }
}
```

However, if I change `yield()` to `delay(1)`, the coroutine is suspended and the test passes.

Why does changing to `runTest` cause this to fail and why does `delay(1)` work but `yield()` does not?

Comment: `delay(1)` probably takes longer than `yield()`. What are the values of `job1Finish` and `job2Finish` in both cases?

Comment: another issue here: locked isn't set to true until job1 starts executing. Seems like it's possible for job2 to execute first, and decide right away it doesn't need to do anything because locked is still false.

Comment: @dnault, the values are 622541 and 3125 which give a difference of approximately 620 microseconds. Presumably they're very small due to the test using virtual time and skipping delays.

I've tried changing the clock to an implementation that uses the TestCoroutineScheduler's virtual time. In this case, the test still gets stuck on `yield` wich prevents virtual time advancing so the test runs until runTest times out.

Your second point is a good one but debugging shows that job1 runs first.

Comment: The values are 3208 and 845000 for delay(1) which gives a difference of approximately -850 microseconds.